# @angular-architects/module-federation version 14.3.0 unhandled exception occurred with webpack.config.js

Tags: webpack-module-federation

We upgraded from @angular-architects/module-federation 14.2.3 to 14.3.0. After upgrading I am seeing an error (pasted below) when trying to serve the application now.

```
Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...An unhandled exception occurred: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object See "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-1b2NOF\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Inside the error log it contains a stack that seems to point to our webpack.config.js as the cause of the error. I pasted what is inside the error log file below:

```
[error] TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:388:5)
    at validateString (node:internal/validators:114:11)
    at Object.join (node:path:429:7)
    at readConfiguredSecondaries (C:\code\client\node_modules\@angular-architects\module-federation\src\utils\share-utils.js:126:94)
    at getSecondaries (C:\code\client\node_modules\@angular-architects\module-federation\src\utils\share-utils.js:96:24)
    at Object.share (C:\code\client\node_modules\@angular-architects\module-federation\src\utils\share-utils.js:175:33)
    at shareAll (C:\code\client\node_modules\@angular-architects\module-federation\src\utils\share-utils.js:143:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\code\client\webpack.config.js:50:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1112:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1166:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:834:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1012:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at transforms.<computed> [as webpackConfiguration] (C:\code\client\node_modules\ngx-build-plus\src\utils\index.js:56:38)
    at setup (C:\code\client\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\builders\dev-server\index.js:168:46)
```

I also pasted what I have in my webpack.config.js below. This error showed up with no changes being made to the webpack.config.js. It just started once we saw the upgrade to the @angular-architects/module-federation 14.3.0 version

```
const { share,  withModuleFederationPlugin, = require('@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack');

module.exports = withModuleFederationPlugin({
  remotes: { },

  shared: share({
    '@angular/core': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto', },
    '@angular/common': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto', },
    '@angular/common/http': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto', },
    '@angular/router': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto', },
    '@okta/okta-angular': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto', },
    '@okta/okta-auth-js': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto', },
  }),

  sharedMappings: ['auth-lib'],
});
```

The whole reason we upgraded to 14.3.0 is because of this article. We want a solution where we don't need to hardcode the URL for the remoteEntry.js file.

To fix this error do we need to adjust how the webpack.config.js file is configured?

I tried to make change to the webpack.config.js file based on what I saw in this link https://github.com/angular-architects/module-federation-plugin/blob/main/libs/mf/tutorial/tutorial.md#bonus---part-6-explicitly-configure-shared-dependencies